# Missing Push Notification Entitlement. the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I am now working on an app using Apple Push Notification.

And as far as testing goes, it works fine, but Apple keeps emailing me the message below.

I have read on the net, and done as much as I can to avoid this. My App ID is enabled for Push Notification, regenerating my Provisioning Profile (a number of times), refreshing my Accounts in Xcode Preferences and ….
But it keeps coming whatever I do. Am I missing some point? Or should I just ignore it? I fear if I ignore it my app may be rejected.

Anyone with a similar experience?

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "TheAppABC”. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.*
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 2):

This messages shows up when the AppId used for provisioning doesn't added up with Push Notification services.

Hope you created AppId without Push services and created mobile provisioning with it, later you added up with push services, forget to recreate the mobile provision with it. And you didn't mention about your APNS Certificate. And also you must do exact same thing you did on development process for distribution process...

Please follow this link, hope this helps:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I don't think they will reject the app, but Push Services will not work...

It should look like this if everything is added perfectly:

[image: you should see aps-environment]

Comment: My appID has push and I recreated my provisioning profile many times, I am still getting this message. This is giving me headaches. And the app works with the push.

Comment: I just noticed that "aps-environment production", visible on your screenshot is not present in my case. Is this important? And if YES, what do I need to do to change this?

Comment: At this point I have even rebuilt the project, recreating the Provisioning profiles in the right order .... and I still get the same message from Apple, I have not idea what is going on. Other than give up, submit the app and see what happens I don't know what I can do. And of course I want the notifications to work.

Comment: Hii Michel yes it's important,this says that your distribution mobile provision wasn't configured up with APNS,might be problem with your xcode provision auto configure,try with removing the account from preference use with local sign entitlements,everything will work..

Comment: If I remove  the account from preference, later when I want to make the archive it says that I need an account. And then I get the same problem again. I have no idea wether I am doing something wrong or there is a bug in Xcode somewhere. But I cannot spend days and days .... and maybe find a solution, may be not. My app may have to work without notification.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "use with local sign entitlements"?
How can I try that?